# Android vlc rtsp speed delay

Tags: android, vlc, rtsp, latency

I'm using this source(https://github.com/vkdinventor/MyVlcPlayer) to build an rtsp client using vlc.

My issue is that it has about 1.5~2.5sec delay even if the server device is right next to me.

I tried to lower the streaming server's quality(1080p->480p, bitrate 8m->1m), but I am still facing the same issue.

On the Logcat, I keep seeing this kind of message over and over again.

core video output: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 116 ms)

Why should this happen? I'm running this application on galaxy s7(android 6.0.1).

The server thing runs inside a small(a size of my hand) linux based pc with a camera.

My question is,

1. Why is this delay happenning? What else can I do other to lowering the streaming quality?
2. When I use a pc as a client, there is about a second time lag, still shorter than the delay occurring on android. When doing decoding, is the processor of the laptop more powerful than the processor of a smartphone?